# Is there some JS library that helps split image to the regions and draws their borders

Tags: javascript, image, image-processing

Hi guys basically we need some library to convert picture like this http://clip2net.com/s/3vLcirT
to the picture like this
http://clip2net.com/s/3vLcbvY
Ideally, after that know the borders of each colour chain after that.

I did find Freeman Chain Code algorithm but seems it is not implemented in JavaScript. Any comments?